# How can I use a pointer (reference) in java?

Tags: java, pointers, reference

This code in c++

```
void generate_moves(char _board[9], std::list<int> &move_list) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        if(_board[i] == 0) {
            move_list.push_back(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to code like that but in java. How can I do it?

Comment: You cannot use pointers in java explicitly

Comment: http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis1xx/resources/JavaForCppProgrammers/j-javac-cpp-ltr.pdf and many many more ...

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a code transation service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129362/148158)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact translation into Java is :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char[] board = new char[]
        {
            'o', 'o', 'o',
            'x', 'x', 'x',
            'x', 'x', 'x'
        };

        List<int> moves = new ArrayList<int>();
        generateMoves ( board, moves );
    }

    public static void generateMoves(char[] board, List<int> moves )
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; ++i)
        {
            if (board[i] == 0)
            {
                moves.add ( i );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because all objects are considered as passed by pointers in Java. There is no copy unless you specifically do it.

Comment: Actually, all objects are pass by value reference. Also, `char[] board = new char[] { ... };` can be shortened to `char[] board = { ... }`.

Comment: Why does the `int` become a `String`?

Answer (score 2):

```
void generate_moves(char _board[], List<Integer> move_list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < _board.length; ++i) {
        if (_board[i] == 0) {
            move_list.add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @PeterLawrey - I probably would as well. Both styles work, of course, and C++ programmers might be more comfortable with the trailing `[]`. I also don't know what meaning the underscore in the parameter name has to OP.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, Java references will serve more-or-less as a c++ pointer.

```
public void generate_moves(..., List<Integer> move_list) {
 ...
  move_list.push_back(i);
}
```

In this case, the invoking `push_back` on the **reference** move_list is working exactly like your pointer example. The reference is followed to it's object instance, and then the method is invoked.

What you won't be able to do is access positions in array using pointer arithmetic.  That is simply not possible in Java.

Comment: Java references serve more or less as C++ references, not C++ pointers.

Comment: thanks for answering. I want to learn move_list.pushback() does not defined. Why?

Comment: @tedd, based on the differences outlined here, I have to completely disagree.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)

Comment: @Ersin, you have to define that method.  My code is not valid; just a guide

Comment: move_list.push_back(i); means move_list.addLast(i); or move_list.add(i)

Comment: @hvgotcodes - In Java, there is no pointer arithmetic. Also, you cannot construct a "pointer" to another variable (e.g., to pass to a method expecting the method to change the variable value in the calling code. There's no syntax for "dereferencing" a Java reference. (I agree that Java references are more like C++ pointers in that they can be `null` and can be changed. That's why I substituted "more or less" for your "exactly".)

Comment: @ted, ok, i changed the word "exactly" :).  You are talking about the dif between pass by value and pass by reference, which has nothing to do with pointers.  I agree the syntax is different, but that doesn't speak to how similar java references are to pointers.  I agree and wrote that pointer arithmetic doesn't exist in Java.  Let's agree that java references and c++ pointers are similar in some ways and different in other ways.  But I think, for the scenario in the OP, they are quite similar.

Comment: Agreed. Comparing Java to C++ is always tricky; this is just one example.